# How do I hide a question without closing or deleting it?

Tags: support

I want to make a question invisible so that it cannot be closed or deleted, or edited by anyone, without actually closing or deleting it myself.

How do I do this?

I want to come back to it later on and edit it so that it's a better question, but I've previously had problems where questions become almost impossible to return to because because bots automatically close them again if you leave them for too long, or people voting to close them for other reasons, such as contents of the original question rather than the edited version, or because of personal disputes.

Comment: Right everyone I think the discussion about potential reasons the OP is affected by this have run their cause. Let’s park it for now and just focus on the main question at hand if there is anything else to add.

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this.  While you have certain privileges as the poster of the question, you don't technically *own* it to that degree.  Even if you delete the question, a sufficient quorum of high-reputation users could in theory choose to undelete it. (Though I can't see any case when that would actually happen in practice.)

Based on what you describe, though, it sounds like deleting the question is probably what you want.  Only high-rep users will be able to see it (assuming they go looking) or be able to edit it; since nobody will see unless they undelete it, they won't bother. In practice only you will undelete and edit it.

I don't know if calling the high-rep users who care enough about the site to act as community moderators "griefers" is really very constructive though.  They're not "just spamming" the question; they have individually made the decision that the question, as it appears, does not meet one or more of the standards of the community.  It's a multi-step process. One does not simply point to a bunch of questions, say "*I don't like them*" and start closing them.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd advise copying the contents of the question to your computer, or a trusted online personal storage, and then deleting it. That way, no one can mess with it, and when you've figured out how to revise it, you can repost it. It will effectively be invisible, and unable to be edited, closed, or deleted by anyone but yourself until you choose to post it again.

Alternately, you can always copy the contents (and the URL of the question) to one of those locations and then let it stand. When you decide to return to improve the question, if it still exists, you edit it (and possibly campaign for undeletion and/or re-opening if it's in that state) and life moves forward. If it's been entirely expunged, you post the new and improved question to the site, and all is well.

Comment: I've tried that, but because of the way that the system is written if a question has been deliberately downvoted or close voted for insincere reasons and you delete it, you don't delete those down votes and votes to close. They stay on your account. The only way to get rid of them is to edit the question and get people to upvote to cancel out the down votes. On some stacks even having one or two questions that have a zero or - rating can get your account sanctioned.

Comment: @AaarghZombies Eh, my experience has been that on here it takes a pattern of bad questions to get anything bad, especially if you have a decent rep. The only cases I remember involved a serial set of questions involving the same topic raised in bad faith. I don't think you have an issue there yet.